# is there any problemif i place Html.ValidationSummary() outside the form tag

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I am working on asp.net mvc-5 web application, and i have the following form:-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Contact</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

now i want to be showing the `@Html.ValidationSummary` message at the top of the page outside the form tag .. but i am not sure if moving the `@Html.ValidationSummary` outside the form tag is a valid approach to follow ? or `@Html.ValidationSummary` need to be inside a form tag ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Html.ValidationSummary` generally is not somehow "linked" to any form that view can contain, and it deals only with model and its errors in `ModelState`.

So it is prefectly valid to place it anywhere at the page.

Comment: Can confirm that this is the case in MVC 5